# How to verify signed bitcoin messages on my own website?

Tags: json-rpc, message-signing, message-verification

On my website, I want to be able to verify that messages are signed by a certain bitcoin address, similar to how it's done [here](http://brainwallet.org/#verify). From my research it seems I have to use JSON RPC with some sort of verify_message(signature, message, addrtype) function?

Is this the only method for doing this? And if so, does this require me to install bitcoind or armory on my web server?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of bitcoind just for this functionality. Look at the code on the brainwallet.org page you posted: http://brainwallet.org/js/bitcoinsig.js

It seems like you could take this exact code and implement it on the server-side with a JavaScript interpreter such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

It depends on the programming language you're using but I'm sure this functionality is available in most of the bitcoin libraries: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Libraries